# Angular: utils/util.js -> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, dependencies, web3js

I feel like this should be resolved simply, but after several attempts, I'm just not coming to a resolution.

Here is the error I've received:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
> 38509 @ [PathToProject]\node_modules\util\util.js:109

This is getting triggered when I instantiate web3 into a clean/new site (there's two other 'test' components, one link one button)

I've searched and found numerous bits of information suggesting that

- *process* is a server side 'node' var, and I can set this to be available client-side by adding to my webpack.config.js, which I have done.
- I might be able to resolve by just declaring a global angular var in my app.component.ts, but it seems this dependency project .js file is not accessing it.

I've also tried just updating the dependency project directly, but even with a compile, it seems that my changes are not being distributed into the webpack build /dist/ result.

I think this probably has a blatantly simple solution, but I'm just overlooking it. I'm just spinning my tires here and could use a little help, but I'm the first in my circle to venture into web3 and don't have a close friend to bounce this off of. Can someone here provide some insight or an alternative resolve this issue?

Relevant bits of code:

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(sass|less|css|ts)$/,
          use: [
            'ts-loader'
          ],
        }
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'develop',
        })
    ],
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [ '.js', '.ts', '.html' ],
      modules: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/'),
          path.resolve("", "src")
      ],
      alias: {
          Environments: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/environments/'),
      },
      fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "path": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        "stream": false,
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),  
    }, 
    }
}
```

global-constants.ts

```
export class GlobalConstants {
    public static process: any  = {
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: 'development'
        }
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{ GlobalConstants } from './common/global-constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Cool Title';
  process = GlobalConstants.process;
}
```

Relevant bit of utils/util.js (line 106-116)

```
var debugs = {};
var debugEnvRegex = /^$/;

if (process.env.NODE_DEBUG) {
  var debugEnv = process.env.NODE_DEBUG;
  debugEnv = debugEnv.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+?.]/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/\*/g, '.*')
    .replace(/,/g, '$|^')
    .toUpperCase();
  debugEnvRegex = new RegExp('^' + debugEnv + '$', 'i');
}
```

Comment: Found your question 1 day later, having the exact same problem.  Where are you importing `util`?

Comment: Util is a few levels deep: \n
main.js -> using web3 \n
web3 index.js -> require('web3-core') \n
web3-core index.js -> require("web3-core-requestmanager"); \n
web3-core-requestmanager index.js -> require('util'); \n\n

I've been searching for 2+ days now, most solutions are to use webpack DefinePlugin, but that makes no difference in my case. Wonder if this is due to recent changes in one of these libs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to polyfills.ts (usually inside src directory):

```
    (window as any).global = window;
    global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
    global.process = require('process');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had no clue how to leverage polyfill.
With some additional troubleshooting, I was able to get my page to at least execute without error.

Comment: Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process' in ...

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i util
npm i process
```

And add types:["node"] in tsconfig.json within compiler options

and merge the webpack config with process

```
merge(webpackConfig, {
    plugins:[
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser'
      })
    ]
  })
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by correcting the import statement. I had accidentally used the router from the Node Express module instead of the one from @angular/router.